# Get the Approval Process Version Name/Number of a doc with Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-shared-drive

There is a recent "Approvals" feature in Google Docs that is currently available only for:

Google Workspace Essentials, Business Standard, Business Plus, Enterprise Essentials, Enterprise Standard, Enterprise Plus, Education Plus, and Nonprofits, as well as G Suite Business, G Suite Enterprise, Drive Enterprise, G Suite for Education, G Suite Enterprise for Education, and G Suite for Nonprofits

Not available to Google Workspace Business Starter, Education Fundamentals, Education Standard, Frontline, and G Suite Basic customers

Not available to users with personal Google Accounts

Here is a brief description of the process:
https://gsuitetips.com/tips/docs/how-to-request-approvals-in-google-docs/

Each approved version of the document will receive a Version name like "Version 1", "Version 2" etc.

I am looking for a way to get this version name using Google Apps script and add it to the document footer.

I have tried the code snippet from
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_revisions

```
/**
 * Lists the revisions of a given file. Note that some properties of revisions
 * are only available for certain file types. For example, G Suite application
 * files do not consume space in Google Drive and thus list a file size of 0.
 * @param {string} fileId The ID of the file to list revisions for.
 */
function listRevisions(fileId) {
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) {
      var revision = revisions.items[i];
      var date = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
      Logger.log('Date: %s, File size (bytes): %s', date.toLocaleString(),
          revision.fileSize);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No revisions found.');
  }
}
```

but this is getting the revision numbers of files that are not the same as the version numbers of the Approval process.

Is there any way to get the version numbers of the Approval process? Thanks.

[image: Approval Versions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it. The only way to interact with the approval system is via web UI. There is still no available documentation on the approval feature on the Drive API. (Give it time since this is still recent)

Although, this was already requested as a missing feature [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208025958) and so far, has no development updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot Octavia, I suspected that this is not possible yet, since the Approval feature is still marked as "New", but it was worth a try to ask and make sure I am not missing something new. 

We will look for an alternative for now, a less convenient solution, like adding a button for the last editor to start a script that would name the current revision of the file with a name identical with the Approval name. 

This way if both the Revision name and Approval version names are identical, then the script can simply use the revision names instead.

Comment: That's a great alternative. Just check the request filed as it may have some updates later on.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any updates on this