# Set Approval Path and Revisions for a Google Doc through App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have been fumbeling with this for a while, with no luck.  I want to create an APpScript for Google Docs where when I select it from a menu item it sets the Approvers for the Document and sets revisions to keep all.  Any help greatly appreciated

Have tried something along these lines (which was suggested by Google Bard!)

```
function submitQuote() {
  // Get the current document.
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  // Set the approval path.
  document.setApprovalPath(['approver@somewhere.com']);

  // Set the revision to keep forever.
  document.setKeepRevisions(true);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the Approval Process Version Name/Number of a doc with Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383476/get-the-approval-process-version-name-number-of-a-doc-with-apps-script)